# Fixed button below scrollview not showing

Tags: java, android

I want to create a scrollview with items I add programmatically and at the bottom a fixed button. But with the code below I see no button.

The code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list_warrantys"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/show_warratys"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_warranty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:text="@string/add_button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Pciture of screen]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/list_warrantys"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_above="@+id/add_warranty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_warratys"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/add_warranty"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:text="@string/add_button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>
```

Use `RelativeLayout` as root and set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your button and `android:layout_above="@+id/add_warranty"` to your `ScrollView`